# How to delegate click event to children of jQuery element array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two elements and I want to delegate click event to their children.
This code works:

```
list.on('click', '> *', function (e) {
    clickHandler($(this), e);
});
listSelected.on('click', '> *', function (e) {
    clickHandler($(this), e);
});
```

Tried to use jQuery element array, but this code doesn't work:

```
$([list, listSelected]).on('click', '> *', function (e) {
    clickHandler($(this), e);
});
```

Comment: list and listSelected have to be DOM elements, not jQuery elements in order to pass as an array of selectors

Comment: @Teemu - accoring to documentation this is called delegated event or do I miss something? [http://api.jquery.com/on/](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: @iGidas Looks like I've missed the fact, that you can ofcourse _delegate_ to many elements too : ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `add()`

```
list.add(listSelected).on('click', '> *', function (e) {
    clickHandler($(this), e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#your_list').children().each(function(){
    $(this).bind('click', clickHandler) ;
}) ;
```

Comment: Note: you should use .on() instead of bind as of jQuery 1.7+